# changing styles object display from 'none' to 'flex' on a condition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component that I wish to hide until I load certain content in my app. Currently I am using a styles object to style the component. I would like to change the styles={display:'none'} to styles={display:'flex'} upon running a function. Currently I am trying to change the style object then pass it to the speech component but it will not hide the buttons entirely. I can only get their styling to change to the point where they exist as gray backgrounds. Can someone help?

```
  showAudio = () =>{
    this.setState({showBtn: true})
    console.log("show buttons")
  }

audioStyles = () =>{
    if(this.state.showBtn===false){
    var styles={
      container: {

        transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)',
        zIndex: '4',
        width: '10%',
        display: 'none',
        margin: 'auto'

        },
        play: {
          button: {
            width: '2em',
            height: '2em',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            outline: 'hidden',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            border: 'hidden',
            display: 'hidden',
            borderRadius: 6
          }
        },
        pause: {
          button: {
            width: '2em',
            height: '2em',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            outline: 'none',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            border: 'none',
            display: 'hidden',
            borderRadius: 6
          },
        },

        resume: {
          button: {
            width: '2em',
            height: '2em',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            pointerEvents: 'none',
            outline: 'none',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            border: 'none',
            display: 'hidden',
            borderRadius: 6
          },
        }
      };


    }else{
    var styles={
        container: {

          transform: 'translate(0%, 0%)',
          zIndex: '4',
          width: '10%',
          display: 'flex',
          margin: 'auto'
          },
          play: {
            button: {
              width: '2em',
              height: '2em',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              pointerEvents: 'none',
              outline: 'none',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              border: 'none',
              borderRadius: 6
            }
          },
          pause: {
            button: {
              width: '2em',
              height: '2em',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              pointerEvents: 'none',
              outline: 'none',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              border: 'none',
              borderRadius: 6
            },
          },

          resume: {
            button: {
              width: '2em',
              height: '2em',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              pointerEvents: 'none',
              outline: 'none',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              border: 'none',
              borderRadius: 6
            },
          }
      }
    }
        return styles
    }


// my speech component which is being styled

<Speech id = "speechModule" text= {this.state.textToReadAloud} resume={true} pause={true} styles={this.audioStyles} rate={0.8} voice="Google UK English Female"/>
```

I expect the entire series of buttons that are rendered from the component to be entirely hidden. If someone can show me how to hide the entire component that would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern to achieve your goal.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        isDone: false
    }
  }

  doSomething() {
    // do something here

    // after everything is done change the state isDone to true
    this.setState({
        isDone: true
    });    
  }

  render() {
    let content = '<p>Loading...</p>';

    if (this.state.isDone) {
        content = '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
    }

    return content;
  }

}
```

So let me explain it to you, first when initializing a component we set the default state `isDone` to false, then after that the `render()` will be triggered and will check if `this.state.isDone` is whether true or false. The value of `content` is depending on your state. Then you may call `doSomething()` method to change your state according to the need of your application. After calling `doSomething()`, `render()` will execute again because we change the state of our component by using `this.setState()` method.

Comment: Glad to help :)